# Undefined index in php when using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html

My Form page :

```
<body>  
<head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script>
        function val()
        {
            var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
            if(name == '')
            {
                alert(name+" is empty");
            }
            else
            {
            var dataString = "name = "+name;
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"hi.php",
                data:dataString,
                cache:false,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#msg').html(html);
                }
            });
            }
        return false;
        }
        </script>

    </head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="name" >
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value ="submit" onclick="return val()">
    </form>
<p id="msg"></p>
</body>
```

Here is my hi.php file

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
echo "Response : ".$name;
?>
```

When clicking on submit button it show an error   `Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\SendEmailAjaxJquery\hi.php on line 2`

I don't know where is the error plz help me to find out the error...

Thanks in advance

Comment: in your ajax data change to

     `data:{name:name},`

Comment: Check the output of `var_export($_POST);` on the PHP side.

Comment: I think those spaces are causing the issue.

Comment: always try printing the received data from ajax before using it, so that you can be sure about what is being received on what indexes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined index: Error in ajax POST and/or php script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136667/undefined-index-error-in-ajax-post-and-or-php-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in place of this

```
var dataString = "name = "+name;
```

change into this

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name;
```

i have the same case here you will be guided from it.

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="content">
    <input type="text" class="search" id="searchid" placeholder="Search for    people" />
    <div id="result"></div>
 </div>  
 </body> 
 </html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  $(".search").keyup(function() 
  { 
    var searchid = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
    if(searchid!='')
    {
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "result.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html)
      {
         $("#result").html(html).show();
      }
     });
   }return false;    
   });
```

Comment: And how would that help?

Comment: You can see it now @Ani Menon

Comment: Thanks its working now... just silly mistake it was... really its helpful thanks  again...

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"hi.php",
  data: {name: name},
  cache:false,
  success:function(html){
    $('#msg').html(html);
  }
});
```

jQuery ajax data setting accept Object to customize the key. For example:

```
data: {anything: "123"}
```

In PHP:

```
echo $_POST["anything"]; //123
```

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax data change to

```
 data:{ 'name' : name }
```